# How to pass props conditionally to a component in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props, react-component

I have a component called "Switch", it takes a few parameters such as label, name, onChange, selected etc..

Now, in my scenario I'm calling an API and getting response. In JSON response, I have value of a field as "Yes" or "No".

I need to pass "switched" to the component if the value is "Yes", otherwise do not pass anything.

```
          <Switch
            label={field.label}
            name={field.fieldID}
            disabled={field.disabled}
            onChange={this.getNextFields}
            checked
          >
            {field.control.modes[0].options.map((option, index) => {
              return (
                
                  <Strong>{option.key}</Strong>
                
              );
            })}
          </Switch>
```

How do I pass it? I'm trying to use ternary operator. But no luck. Your help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Use a ternary operator and return undefined if false. For example: <Strong propName={(condition) ? propValue : undefined} />

Comment: I tried it, but the problem is "checked" doesn't take any values, I need to pass "checked" to the component if "Yes" otherwise do not pass anything.
@ValeriF21 Thanks for your reply

Comment: Passing undefined with some prop is the same as passing nothing, in both cases if you try to access this prop in the Component the value will be undefined.

Comment: I've added the condition as "checked={field.value === 'Yes' ? true : (field.value==="No"? false : undefined)}" and it's working as expected for me. Thanks for your time and reply.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ternary operator in the prop definition.

```js
<Switch
  label={field.label}
  name={field.fieldID}
  disabled={field.disabled}
  onChange={this.getNextFields}
  checked={{ Yes: true, No: false }[field.value]}
>
  {field.control.modes[0].options.map((option, index) => {
    return <Strong>{option.key}</Strong>;
  })}
</Switch>
```

Comment: I tried it, but the problem is "checked" doesn't take any values, I need to pass "checked" to the component if "Yes" otherwise do not pass anything.

Comment: @vg527 I've updated the code snippet to use the checked propname instead of "switched". `checked` by iitself is a boolean prop. React JSX allows you to pass boolean props with an optional value of true or false. You can explicitly pass true or false as demonstrated in my code snippet.

Comment: Brilliant, that worked! I did a slight change to the condition as "checked={field.value === 'Yes' ? true : (field.value==="No"? false : undefined)}"
Please correct, if this is wrong.

Comment: @vg527 yes, that will work too. But we can do better. Let's explicitly map Yes and No to true and false. Then we get the value using bracket notation. If the value is neither Yes nor No, then the value will be undefined. See the updated code snippet.

Comment: That works too. Thanks Mate, much appreciated!

Comment: Another question on the same component, On change of value, I need to call a function and pass the selected value to that function. I wrote a function and it's being invoked correctly and working as expected - `onChange={() => this.getNextFields("Yes")}`
How do I pass the selected value dynamically to the function? Please help

Comment: @vg527 try this `onChange={(e) => this.getNextFields(e.target.checked)}`

Comment: @vg527 oh, actually, you need to pass 'Yes' or 'No'? correct? Try this `onChange={(e) => this.getNextFields({ true: 'Yes', false: 'No' }[e.target.checked])}`

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this -

```html
<Switch
  label={field.label}
  name={field.fieldID}
  disabled={field.disabled}
  onChange={this.getNextFields}
  checked={field.value === 'Yes' ? 'switched' : ''}
>
  {field.control.modes[0].options.map((option, index) => {
    return (               
      <Strong>{option.key}</Strong>
                    
    );
  })}
</Switch>
```